# Input Element is not Shown Inline

Tags: html, css

We have an `input` element besides two buttons inside a `div`, which is inside of a `td`. I don't quite understand, how to put all children of the *div* in one line, when its parent (the `td`) has a width.

Here is [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/bair_web/mL7bcn2x/).

I could set the width of the input element to 65% e.g., but this is a hack only.

Does someone know, why the input elements takes all the width **if** the table cell has a width-attribute? I did not find any hint [in the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-input-element).

How can I set the input element (`display`) inline nonetheless? `display: flex` for the *div* (like it has been [suggested for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52488480/force-html-input-to-display-inline-with-buttons))?

## Survival Kit

#### HTML

```
<p>Input takes all width?</p>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="163px">
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="some-field" />
                    <button class="symbol" type="button"></button>
                    <button class="symbol" type="button"></button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

#### CSS

```
button.symbol {
    border-width: 0;
    background: white;
    display: inline;
}
button.symbol::before {
    content: '\0394';
}
input {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: input has a default width so you will simply have line break if the width you define is not enough for the input + the content

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622086/widthauto-for-input-fields

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421361/input-button-elements-not-shrinking-in-a-flex-container

Comment: One [more link](https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d).

Answer (score 0):

> Does someone know, why the input elements takes all the width if the table cell has a width-attribute?

It is not so. `input` elements of `type="text"` have a default `size` of 20, which can result in different *widths* (depending on font, font-size etc.).

In your case, you have given `163px` width to your `td`. If you increase the width to say `250px`, all the elements will fit in a row.

For eg.:

```css
button.symbol {
  border-width: 0;
  background: white;
  display: inline;
}
button.symbol::before {
  content: '\0394';
}
input {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<p>Input takes all width?</p>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="250px">
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="some-field" />
          <button class="symbol" type="button"></button>
          <button class="symbol" type="button"></button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p>No Width</p>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="some-field" />
          <button class="symbol" type="button"></button>
          <button class="symbol" type="button"></button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: How much is this _default width_ of an input element? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11846241/2092322) we have a hint: it apparently depends on the browser.

Comment: @BairDev as it turns out size and width are two different things, Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480588/input-size-vs-width

Comment: Yeah and the default `size` [seems to be 20](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#attr-input-size), which can result in various _widths_ (depends on font and font-size etc.), but we can see a minimum here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would say (and I am no expert so don't take my word for granted) that it sets the elements next to each other (in your jsfiddle second example), because you never specified a width. So it will align all of them next to each other, since it has no boundaries to keep in 'mind'.
However when you set a width for the `td` it has to keep the boundaries of your `x px` in 'mind'. The default width of an input will be set if you do not specify it. Now, considering your button has a default width aswell. This means it tries to be `inline` or `inline-block`, but 'fails', since it still has boundaries. 
Therefore it DOES work when you set a certain percentage, because it will take `x percentage` relative to its parent.  So either increase the width of your `td` or set `x px` for your buttons and input fields. If this is not an option, you could opt to go for percentages.

But again, I am no guru on this topic, so don't take my word for it. This was my 2 cents.